# Matchit not working

Tags: vim, macvim

I am using Macvim 7.3 snapshot 57. I can't seem to get matchit to work in any of my files.

I press % on an opening tag. It doesn't take me to the closing tag...

My vimrc file:

```
" Pathogen settings
call pathogen#runtime_append_all_bundles()
call pathogen#helptags()

set nocompatible

set number
set ruler
set cursorline
syntax on

" Disable all blinking
set guicursor+=a:blinkon0

" Whitespace stuff
set nowrap
set tabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set expandtab
set cindent
set smartindent
set autoindent
set list listchars=tab:\ \ ,trail:·

" Searching
set hlsearch
set incsearch
set ignorecase
set smartcase

" Status bar
set laststatus=2

" Start without the toolbar
set guioptions-=T

" Default gui color scheme
" "color default
" color molokai
color railscasts+

" Command-/ to toggle comments
map <D-/> :TComment<CR>j

" Remember last location in file
if has("autocmd")
  au BufReadPost * if line("'\"") > 0 && line("'\"") <= line("$")
    \| exe "normal g'\"" | endif
endif

" Thorfile, Rakefile and Gemfile are Ruby
au BufRead,BufNewFile {Gemfile,Rakefile,Thorfile,config.ru} set ft=ruby

" Open split buffers below instead of above current buffer
set splitbelow

" Session options
let g:session_autoload = 1
let g:session_autosave = 1

" Buffer navigation
map <C-K> <C-W><C-K>
map <C-J> <C-W><C-W>
map <C-H> <C-W><C-H>
map <C-L> <C-W><C-L>

" Rails navigation options
nmap <leader>rc :Rcontroller 
nmap <leader>rv :Rview 
nmap <leader>rm :Rmodel 

" Tab completion
" Also needed for better Rails navigation auto-completion
set wildmode=list:longest,list:full

" Open up side panel left (NERDTree) and right(Tagbar)
" nmap <leader>\ :NERDTreeToggle<CR> :TagbarToggle<CR>
nmap <leader>\ :call ToggleNERDTreeAndTagbar()<CR>

" Allow single click for NERDTree
let NERDTreeMouseMode = 3
let g:NERDTreeWinSize = 30
" autocmd VimEnter * NERDTree

" Tagbar options
let tagbar_singleclick = 1
let g:tagbar_sort = 0
let g:tagbar_width = 30
" autocmd VimEnter * nested TagbarOpen

" The Janus plugin sets this to noequalalways for the Zoominfo plugin
" However, we want to set this to equalalways instead, since we want to
" have equal window height when a new window is opened. i.e. via ctrl+w+s
set equalalways

" Matchit already installed in newer versions of vim.
" Don't need to add this onto pathogen bundle folder. We only need
" to configure it.
" Configure matchit so that it goes from opening tag to closing tag
au FileType html,eruby,rb,css,js,xml runtime! macros/matchit.vim

" Set backup and swp dir. Don't forget to clear tmp dir out once in a while
set backupdir=~/.vim/tmp/backup
set directory=~/.vim/tmp/swp

" Detect if a tab was closed, and ensure that height of main window fills the screen (100% height)
au TabEnter * let &lines = 100

" <leader>\ to open or close NERDTree and Tagbar, under the following conditions:
" 1) Only close both if NERDTree and Tagbar are both opened
" 2) Open both if NERDTree and Tagbar are closed OR if one is already opened
function! ToggleNERDTreeAndTagbar()
  let w:jumpbacktohere = 1

  " Detect which plugins are open
  if exists('t:NERDTreeBufName')
      let nerdtree_open = bufwinnr(t:NERDTreeBufName) != -1
  else
      let nerdtree_open = 0
  endif
  let tagbar_open = bufwinnr('__Tagbar__') != -1

  " Perform the appropriate action
  if nerdtree_open && tagbar_open
      NERDTreeClose
      TagbarClose
  elseif nerdtree_open
      TagbarOpen
  elseif tagbar_open
      NERDTree
  else
      NERDTree
      TagbarOpen
  endif

  " Jump back to the original window
  for window in range(1, winnr('$'))
    execute window . 'wincmd w'
    if exists('w:jumpbacktohere')
      unlet w:jumpbacktohere
      break
    endif
  endfor
endfunction
```

Comment: https://github.com/tpope/vim-endwise

Answer (score 30):

Since Vim comes shipped with matchit plugin, all I needed to do was activate it:

```
vim ~/.vimrc
```

Then add the following into your .vimrc:

```
set nocompatible
filetype plugin on
runtime macros/matchit.vim
```

Comment: On MacVim (77) I tried all the other suggestions, this is the only one that worked (the three lines in the `.vimrc`). Thanks!

Comment: My understanding is that the existence of a `~/.vimrc` file automatically turns off Vi compatibility. So says `:help compatible`, as well: "When a |vimrc| or |gvimrc| file is found while Vim is starting up, this option is switched off." Indeed, I omitted the `set nocompatible` line from my `~/.vimrc` file and was still able to use `matchit.vim` by adding the following two lines.

Answer (score 22):

This line

```
runtime macros/matchit.vim
```

is the standard way of activating matchit and it works on all my machines.

Does matchit work after you type

```
:runtime macros/matchit.vim
```

in normal mode ?

Comment: Stupid question: matchit is activated for `html,eruby,rb,css,js,xml`, do you, by any chance try to use it with some other filetype?

Comment: Try `:help matchit-install`, it's specifically written with plugin documentation in mind but it could help you.

Comment: Typing `:runtime macros/matchit.vim` in normal mode doesn't work right away which threw me off. You have to also do a `:filetype detect` to activate it for your open files. `runtime macros/matchit.vim` in vimrc does indeed work.

Comment: This is incredibly helpful, built in and completely non-obvious that it's a better (i.e., functional and maintained) solution than ruby-matchit.vim

Comment: Functional, yes, but maintained?  I have not updated matchit since 2008.

Answer (score 22):

[The page of the `matchit` plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39) says:

Make sure you have a line like

```
:filetype plugin on
```

in your `vimrc` file.  This enables filetype plugins, many of which tell 
`matchit.vim` which matching pairs to use.

Answer (score 9):

FYI: in vim 8 `runtime macros/matchit.vim` becomes `packadd! matchit`.

Comment: Many thanks for letting me know. I suppose this is why this kind of thing is discouraged. I have removed the offending link. For posterity it was this:  https://fossies.org/diffs/vim/7.4_vs_8.0/runtime/macros/matchit.txt-diff.html

Comment: And in case anyone else gets confused like me, the `!` is used in your .vimrc, while if you run the command interactively you must *not* include it.

Answer (score 6):

I started having the same issue after I updated some of my vim plugings to the latest version for 7.3.

But when I run

`:MatchDebug`

it fixes the issue for me.

Comment: Yup, this fixed it for me as well. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: Well, `:MatchDebug` calls `s:Match_debug()`, the first line of which is `let b:match_debug = 1 " Save debugging information.`.  (The rest of the function just defines some menus.)  If you search for `b:match_debug`, you will see that, if it is set, then the script will not use its cached data.

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with matchit finding the correct matching brace in C++/C when there were commented braces. The following steps, taken from [this forum post](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/Install-matchit-td5710177.html) written by [this guy](http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=user_nodes&user=28373), solved it for me and also pretty much explained the way the whole thing works:

1. Create the folder ~/.vim/plugin if it is not already there:

   ```
   mkdir ~/.vim/plugin
   ```
2. Create a file with the name 
   ~/.vim/plugin/matchit.vim :

   ```
   vi ~/.vim/plugin/matchit.vim
   ```

   and the following contents:

   ```
   runtime macros/matchit.vim
   ```
3. Create the directory ~/.vim/doc if it is not already there:

   ```
   mkdir ~/.vim/doc
   ```
4. Copy /usr/share/vim/vim73/macros/matchit.txt to ~/.vim/doc/ :

   ```
   cp /usr/share/vim/vim73/macros/matchit.txt ~/.vim/doc/
   ```
5. Open vi

   ```
   vi
   ```

   and execute the following in it:

   ```
   :helptags ~/.vim/doc
   ```
6. Make sure that your ~/.vimrc includes one of the following:

   ```
   source $VIMRUNTIME/vimrc_example.vim
   ```

   or

   ```
   runtime vimrc_example.vim
   ```

   or

   ```
   filetype plugin on
   ```

   or

   ```
   filetype plugin indent on
   ```
7. Add the following autocommand in your vimrc:

   ```
   " make matchit work on C-like filetypes 
   " c and cpp are already handled by their ftplugin 
   au Filetype css,javascript 
           \ let b:match_words = &matchpairs
   ```
8. Restart Vim.

Comment: What does `let b:match_words = &matchpairs ` do?

Comment: Quick disclaimer: not being the original author (sources cited in my answer) this is my interpretation, which I accepted and therefore used as my solution. Now this is out of the way, it searches and matches closing bracket/parenthesis/etc patterns. You can see some examples here: https://github.com/isaacs/.vim/blob/master/macros/matchit.txt

Answer (score 0):

I've  had similar problem. I've tried `runtime macros/matchit.vim` with VIM-provided script and it didn't work.
So I've downloaded this script in version 1.13.2 from http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=39, unzipped it into ~/vimfiles and it works!