# Setting ft=vb causing vim's parenthesis matching to stop working

Tags: vb.net, vim, file-type

I'm having a weird issue in which I can't get parentheses to match in VB files in vim or gvim.

For example, if I start `vim` and insert `Iif(test, 0, 1)`, I can use `%` to jump between the two parentheses like normal. Then if I run `:set ft=vb`, it stops working. Actually, I get one more jump, then it stops working.

I have tested this on two different machines running Windows and Linux and I get the same results.

Does anyone know why this might be?

Comment: There may be clues to be found by running `:e $VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/vb.vim`.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the *matchit* plugin that comes with Vim. In `$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/vb.vim`, it defines custom pairs (e.g. `If...End If`) which override the default pairs. To re-enable those (in addition), put the following into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/vb.vim`:

```
let b:match_words .= ',(:)'
```

Cp. `:help b:match_words`.

Comment: First of all, `:help b:match_words` only works if you have installed the help file for matchit.  If not, then you can still `:e $VIMRUNTIME/macros/matchit.txt`.  Second of all, matchit uses the standard `'matchpairs'` option as well as `b:match_words`.  In my little test, `:MatchDebug` cleared up the problem.  This seems familiar ...

Comment: Found it:  see my comment on this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/13386769/3130080.  So something is wrong in how matchit caches its search patterns ...